# extjs Stretch items in vertical tab bar to fit west region of border layout

Tags: extjs, tabbar

I have a vertical tab bar and I want the tabitems to stretch horizontally to fit the west region of my border layout.  I have everything in sencha fiddler but I do not know how to share the link so everyone can see my code.  any ideas how to fix this... and share my fiddler?

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {
    //Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');

    var mainVP = Ext.create(Ext.container.Viewport, {
        layout: 'border',
        defaults: {
            style: 'border: 1px solid black'
        },
        items: [{
            html: 'hio',
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            title: 'main tab panel'
        }, {
            html: 'north',
            region: 'north',
            height: 50,
            title: 'this is my header area'
        }, {
            html: 'east',
            region: 'east',
            width: 50
        }, {
            html: 'west',
            region: 'west',
            width: 250,
            title: 'westregion',
            xtype: 'NavigationBar'

            //items: [{
                //xtype: 'button',
                //text: 'click me',
                //listeners: {
                  //  click: function(btn) {
                        //Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');

                    //    btn.up('viewport').down('tabpanel').add({
                      //      xtype: 'clientDetails'
                       // });
                    //}
                //}
            //}]
        }]
    });
}
});

Ext.define('Ext.test1.NavigationBar', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: 'widget.NavigationBar',

tabBar: {
    //width: 250,
    //minTabWidth: 130,
    //maxTabWidth: 240,        
    orientation: 'vertical',
    //defaults: {
    //    flex: 1
    //}
    //dock: 'left',

    //layout: {
    //    pack: 'center'
    //}
},

layout: 'fit',

tabPosition: 'left',

//titleRotation: 0,
tabRotation: 0,

items: [{
    title: 'Home',
    iconCls: 'fa-home',
    layout: 'fit'
    // The following grid shares a store with the classic version's grid as well!
}, {
    title: 'Users',
    iconCls: 'fa-user'
        //layout: 'fit'

}, {
    title: 'Groups',
    iconCls: 'fa-users'
        //layout: 'fit'
}, {
    title: 'Settings',
    iconCls: 'fa-cog'
        //layout: 'fit'
}]
});
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can share your fiddle, by logging in Sencha fiddle with you Sencha forum username & password, than saving the fiddle & copying the url - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gib

Comment: The tabs won't stretch, because the white space is actually there, because it is the tabs content area.  You could put the tabpanel in the main tab panel, you don't acctually need the westregion.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c3f

Comment: I like the border layout so I can have a north and south region as well.  So there is NO way to stretch the tab items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your fiddle a bit - does [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gid) look / work like something you wanted to accomplish?

I removed the `westregion`, and set the center region xtype to `NavigationBar`.
On the `users` tab I added contact details as an item

```
 {
        title: 'Users',
        iconCls: 'fa-user',
             items: [{
                xtype: 'clientDetails'
            }]  
    }
```

If you are using the border layout, you don't need to have *all* of the regions, you only *need* the center one - see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.layout.container.Border.html

Comment: I guess I am going about this the wrong way.  In the original west region I want a mix of that tab panel and a combobox and some labels...  all going down vertically in the left panel.  Is there a way to do that, or should I just keep the west region, and a vbox with buttons instead of a tabpanel, then add a combobox and labels?  - then maybe just make the buttons LOOK similar to the tabpanelItems

Comment: You could try using a panel with accordion layout in the west region - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.layout.container.Accordion.html

Or you could try making the west region a vertical toolbar?  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html